# Why would /etc/krb5.keytab change?

Tags: security, files, intrusion-detection

A half-dozen boxes out of hundreds reported a changed /etc/krb5.keytab all within a few minutes of each other on a random Saturday.  No one was logged in at the time of the changes.  I have asked for copies of the files before the change so I can compare them, but I'm wondering if this is normal or expected behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure what process is used in Linux (some recurring task perhaps), but that is the credentials for the host. On Windows, by default a host changes its password every 30 days. For a fleet of 1,000 hosts, that is about 33 hosts per day updating its own password. "For example, this refreshes the host principal with a keytab in the default location of /etc/krb5.keytab: `ipa-getkeytab -p host/client.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM -s ipa.example.com -k /etc/krb5.keytab`

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/identity_management_guide/configuring_authentication-refreshing_kerberos_tickets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected. The keytab is updated to rotate secrets. This is done regularly, and it's not surprising that it happens at a similar timestamp across systems.

Comment: Appreciate the answer!  I suspected as much. That leaves open issues for file integrity checking that relies on the modify time of a file.  I've developed ignore lists over time, but the vendors keep adding more while failing to add anything I can see to the documentation.